# How Can i Execute grep in a Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

When i do the following i get results:

```
bash$ cat launched | egrep MyTest
MyTest
```

but with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
result= `cat launched | grep MyTest`
echo $result
```

when launching the script i get:

```
bash$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: MyTest: not found
```

I have full access rights on the script and the script is launched in the same directory as the file launched. How can i fix the script so it will return the same result as above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the space:

```
result=`cat launched | grep MyTest`
```

Even better, drop the [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat):

```
result=`grep MyTest launched`
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra space:

```
result= `cat launched | grep MyTest`
       ^---
```

variable assignments must not have spaces on either side of the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space before the grave accent and your problems go away